# Ruby on Rails - SoundCloud OAuth 2 undefined method `access_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am working on a making a personal soundcloud app on Rails 5 and i'm having some trouble with OAuth. I'm able to redirect to Soundcloud's app and give permission to my user. When I try to exchange the code for token on redirect_uri,  get an error. I have included my code and image of the error I'm getting below.

```
def connected 

  client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'My ID',
                      :client_secret => 'my secret',
                      :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/login/soundcloud/callback")

  code = params[:code]
  value = client.exchange_token(:code => code) #get an error on this line
 #my code to save access token into db goes here.
end
```

I have added this image

[image]

for the error that I'm getting. I thought it might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issues, so I just did created the request manually for this step. Soundcloud gem is pretty dated, I'm sure it has something to do with that.

```
    @client = Soundcloud.new(client_id: client_id,
                             client_secret: client_secret,
                             redirect_uri:'http://localhost:3000/soundcloud/connected')
    @code = params[:code]
    response = HTTParty.post("https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token",
    body: {
      "client_id" => client_id,
      "client_secret" => client_secret,
      "redirect_uri" => 'http://localhost:3000/soundcloud/connected',
      'grant_type'=> 'authorization_code',
      "code" => @code
      }
  )
  access_token = response["access_token"]
  @authed_client = Soundcloud.new(access_token: access_token)
  soundcloud_user = @authed_client.get('/me')
end
```

Hope this helps.